# Как отразить рандомную строчку из выбранного столбца БД?

Tags: java, sql, cursor

```
String product = "";

        Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT  * FROM " + "book1" + " ORDER BY RANDOM() ", null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            product += cursor.getString(1);

            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();

        text1.setText(product);
```

Нужно в поле text1 (text View) ввести  значение ячейки из определенного выбранного столбца,при коде выше, он выдает весь столбец, а нужно одно значение из столбца. Как это сделать,не изменяя rawQuery? Может нужно что то другое в поле cursor.getString?

Comment: *а нужно одно значение из столбца* Ограничьте количество соотв. предложением (TOP либо LIMIT - зависит от DBMS).

Comment: не хотелось бы сортировать по возможности в rawQuery, чтобы этот кусок кода был потом в цикле do while, соответственно,чтобы каждый раз при определенных действиях выводилась новая строка,а лимит вроде бы помешает

Comment: Формулируйте задачу, а не то, как Вы её собрались решать...

Comment: Дмитрий Плат, если я вас понял, тогда вам нужно получить все значения и уже использовать получившуюся коллекцию. Если значений много получать кусками, ограничивая количество в запросе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> не изменяя rawQuery

Если нужно только первое значение, то не нужно обходить весь столбец:

```
if ((cursor!=null) && (cursor.getCount() > 0)){
   cursor.moveToFirst();
   product += cursor.getString(1);
}
```

Если нет, то также можно сразу "пролистать" курсор:

```
cursor.move(offset);
```

Но, вообще **это жуткий костыль**. Лучше выбирать одну запись при помощи запроса (`LIMIT` и `WHERE` Вам в помощь).